# Basic probability - picking cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I could really use some help with this homework question.

There are 100 cards in a raffle. 1 of them is the winning card.
There are $i$ participants, each one buys 1 card.
What is the probability the no one wins?

**Solution attempt:**

I solved it the following way:

The probability the no one wins:

$$\frac{99}{100} \frac{98}{99} \frac{97}{98} \frac{96}{97} \dots =\frac{\frac{99!}{i!}}{\frac{100!}{i!}} = \frac{99!}{100!} = 0.01 $$

The problem is that the solution I was given by my teacher is:
$$\frac{\binom{99}{i}}{\binom{100}{i}}$$

I seems like the order of choices doesn't matter in this solution. My question is - why? I thought that I should count all the different orders.

Any help would  be greatly appreciated!!

**Edit:**
I finally understood my mistake!!

$$\frac{99}{100} \frac{98}{99} \frac{97}{98} \frac{96}{97} \dots =\frac{\frac{99!}{(90-i)!}}{\frac{100!}{(100-i)!}}$$ and this is equivalent..

Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Somehow I would have thought the quicker answer was the number of unsold tickets divided by the total number of tickets $\dfrac{100-i}{100}$.  Your answer does not seem  to depend on $i$

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: There are $100$ tickets or cards.  $i$ are sold and $100-i$ are not.  Each is equally likely to be the winning ticket

Comment: Okay I understand this solution from this point of view.. But why is the mistake in my first attempt?

Comment: What is the probability to win if you buy $i$ tickets? Now, subtract that from $1$.

Comment: @Vasya But why is this equivalent? There are $i$ different people.. The case in which the first person draws the winning card and the case in which the second person draws it are different, aren't they?

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess: Not really, because if the first one buys a winning card, we know for sure that the second won't win. It's like you have $i$ attempts to win. Anyway, your mistake is that the denominators in your expressions should be $(99-i)!$ and $(100-i)!$